# can we merge two parquet files into one which has different datatypes to the columns using the pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark-schema

when I am trying the merge the two parquets file into one with different datatypes. I'm getting this error an error occurred while calling o94.parquet. Failed merging schema: because in one file it has column of Boolean and for another it has int datatype the column names are same.

I want merge both parquet files into one with different datatypes without using the cast or union method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.